# calling stored procedure in form button in ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-apex

Hi I have created stored procedures using PL/SQL. Now I want to call my procedure from a button, I already have taken 2 text fields does anyone help me how i could call my procedure into the button

Comment: Create a dynamic action that executes a pl/sql block code and from there call the stored procedure

Comment: What will your procedure do?  The normal case is for the button to submit the page, and then you write an "on page submit" process to call the procedure.

Comment: thanks guys i have done ith it what i need was to call my method on the process :)

Comment: @Typo How to create Dynamic Action that executes a pl/sql block code? I created one but it fires on every Page Load event on that page, even I set Fire On Page Load to No.